# MMC (Microsoft Management Console) has detected an error in a snap-in and will unload it

Tags: windows-7, windows-server, windows-task-scheduler, event-viewer, mmc

**Error showing up in Windows 7 or Windows Server based computers.**

This error shows up when launching multiple windows system applications such as:

1. `Windows Event Viewer`
2. `Windows Task Scheduler`
3. `Windows Activation Management Tool`

**The error shows up like below:**

1. [image]
2. [image]
3. [image]

Error from stack trace:

> at
> Microsoft.ManagementConsole.Internal.SnapInMessagePumpProxy.OnThreadException(Object
> sender, ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.OnThreadException(Exception
> t)    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProcException(Exception e)
> at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg,
> IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CallWindowProc(IntPtr
> wndProc, IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DefWndProc(Message& m)    at
> Microsoft.Windows.ManagementUI.CombinedControls.ListViewEx.DefWndProc(Message&
> m)    at System.Windows.Forms.ListView.WndProc(Message& m)    at
> Microsoft.Windows.ManagementUI.CombinedControls.ListViewEx.WndProc(Message&
> m)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
> at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg,
> IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

Comment: I researched this issue online and found that 1) Hotfix Rollup 2688730 for Windows 7 SP1 (which is what I have) ought to fix this issue, and 2) it does not appear to have been installed on my machine, but I have a problem: I can’t find a download link! (Only the hotfix description at [a Microsoft announcement page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2688730/hotfix-rollup-2688730-is-available-for-the--net-framework-2-0-sp2-on-w).)

Comment: Okay I just remembered that to get any hotfix from Microsoft, there's a [URL you can use](http://support.microsoft.com/hotfix/KBHotfix.aspx?kbnum=**2688730**&kbln=en-us). You just substitute the KB number in it.

I visited this site and provided my e-mail address. I then got a an e-mail message from Microsoft.com to help me download [the actual hotfix](http://hotfixv4.microsoft.com/.Net%20Framework%202.0%20–%20Win7%20SP1,%20Windows%20Server%202008%20R2%20SP1%20(CBS)/sp1/DevDiv965999/50727.5723/free/446502_intl_x64_zip.exe).

However it did not work! I am still experiencing the same issue.

Comment: General software problems, such as this one, belongs on [su], not on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Can it be moved over to Superuser without losing the threads here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First, Download the Hotfix**

Okay, as I commented earlier, Microsoft claimed to have fixed this issue with KB2688730 at:

[http://support.microsoft.com/hotfix/KBHotfix.aspx?kbnum=**2688730**&kbln=en-us](http://support.microsoft.com/hotfix/KBHotfix.aspx?kbnum=2688730&kbln=en-us)

After visiting this site and providing it my e-mail address, I got a link in an e-mail message from Microsoft.com to help me download the actual hotfix:

[http://hotfixv4.microsoft.com/.Net%20Framework%202.0%20–%20Win7%20SP1,%20Windows%20Server%202008%20R2%20SP1%20(CBS)/sp1/DevDiv965999/50727.5723/free/446502_intl_x64_zip.exe](http://hotfixv4.microsoft.com/.Net%20Framework%202.0%20%E2%80%93%20Win7%20SP1,%20Windows%20Server%202008%20R2%20SP1%20(CBS)/sp1/DevDiv965999/50727.5723/free/446502_intl_x64_zip.exe)

**Finally, Apply .NET Framework 3.5.1**

Now installing that alone won't completely fix the problem ...unless, as I found out today, you also have Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5.1 installed and "turned on". In order to do so, go to the Windows Control Panel, and visit the Programs and Features applet. When it appears, click the hyperlink on the left sidebar titled, "Turn Windows features on or off".

[image]

Then a smaller dialog box will appear with a list of Windows components. Right now, the only thing that's important is that you place a checkmark on the Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5.1 item (and its subitems). Then click OK. That's it!

[image]

After this, I was immediately able to right-click on the Windows Event Viewer log and get my expected context menu instead of the previous errors I was getting!

[image]

Comment: Now here's a catch-22: I'm a developer, and it appears this fix breaks Nuget on my Visual Studio 2013 installation because afterward it just cycles endlessly saying it's "Retrieving information...". If I reinstall Nuget, that corrects that, but then it seems this inadvertently brings back the originally posted issue citing an MMC snap-in error in Event Viewer when you right-click the log!